# How to create a Java web service program on Java 5 or older, on UNIX platform

Tags: java, web-services, unix, javac, java-5

I am working on a project that requires me to deploy a web-service.
The working platform is UNIX and the Java version that it is using is Java 5.

I have tried few basic web service on UNIX, but do not know how to use external lib for this action.

I have copied lib rt.jar and created a java class in src folder tried to complied it:

```
# javac -classpath lib/rt.jar src/TestService.java
```

shows this error :

```
@webservice illegal character
```

I am expecting the required external lib and to run this on Java 5, and need help for using external lib for running java code.

Here is my code to demonstrate the problem:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod; 
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint; 

WebService SOAPBinding(style= SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT) 
public class TestService { 
    WebMethod public String sayHello(String msg){ return "Hello "+msg; } 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Endpoint.publish("localhost:8888/testWS", new TestService()); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Java ... 5?! Lol. In any case, Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], explain what exactly `@webservice` is. Clarify please!

Comment: please find the below class:

Comment: please find the below class: import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
 
WebService
SOAPBinding(style= SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
public class TestService {
WebMethod
public String sayHello(String msg){
return "Hello "+msg;
}
 
public static void main(String[] args){
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8888/testWS", new TestService());
}
}

Comment: Welcome Anand! I've edited your code into your question. You can further edit your question by clicking the "edit" link below it. Try to get relevant information in the question itself - not everybody reads comments.

Comment: @JoopEggen Annotations were introduced in Java 5.  See, for instance, [@Override](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Override.html).

Comment: @VGR my mistake, indeed.